Applying the optional sampling theorem to a truncated martingale
This is to discuss applicability of the Optional sampling theorem, Theorem 1.3.22 of Karatzas and Shreve.
[Theorem 1.3.22 of KS98 book] Let $(X_t, \mathcal F_t: 0 \le t\le \infty)$ be a
right-continuous submartingale with a last element $X_\infty$,
and let $S\le T$ be two optional times of the filtration
$\mathcal F_t$. Then, we have
$$
    \mathbb E[X_T | \mathcal F_{S+}] \ge X_S, \quad \text{a.s.} P.
$$
If $S$ is a stopping time, then $\mathcal F_S$ can replace
$\mathcal F_{S+}$ in the above equation.
In particular, $\mathbb E X_T \ge X_0$,
and for a martingale with a last element,
we have $\mathbb E X_T = X_0$.
Now, let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion.
Then, it is a martingale.
But optional sampling theorem does not hold
for $W$ because it does not have an integrable
last element $W_{\infty} = \lim_{t \to \infty} W_t$.
This point can be also seen from the fact that
$\mathbb E W_T = 1 \neq 0 = W_0$
for the stopping time $T = \inf (t \ge 0: W_t = 1)$.
Now define a truncated BM process $W_t^T = W_{t \wedge T}$.
Then, $W_t^T$ is a martingale with an integrable last
element $W^T_\infty = 1$.
Therefore, optional sampling theorem should hold for $W^T$.
However, we still have a counterexample:
$\mathbb E W_T^T = 1 \neq 0 = W_0^T$.
What is wrong in this argument?

I cannot see the theorem in your link. You may want to copy the theorem into your question.

A martingale $(X_t){t\geq 0}$ has a $\mathscr{F}\infty$-measurable last element $X_\infty$ if $E[X_\infty|\mathscr{F}t]=X_t$ a.s. for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ (this is the K-S definition). So, $W{\tau}=1$ (a.s.) is not the last element of $X_t=W_{\tau\wedge t}$.

@Wei I added the theorem

@Snoop You are probably right. Where can I find the definition of the last element in the book?

@user79963 at the beginning of "A. Fundamental Inequalities " p. 12 in the link provided.

@Snoop Thank you, I found it. I thought the last element is in the almost sure sense.

@Snoop please post the answer, thank you.

The Karatzas-Shreve definition of last element of a martingale can be found in the reference at the beginning of the section 'A. Fundamental Inequalities' p. 12 (OP has also posted a link with the reference available there). In the K-S sense, a martingale $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ has a $\mathscr{F}_\infty$-measurable last element $X_\infty$ if $E[X_\infty|\mathscr{F}_t]=X_t$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$. In this case, if $X_t=W_{\tau\wedge t}$, then $W_\tau=1$ (a.s.) is not a last element of $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ - hence why the mentioned optional stopping argument does not hold.

Because the stopped process is a martingale you get $\Bbb E[W_{T\wedge t}]=0$ for each $t>0$. Or, expanded:
$$
0=\Bbb P[T\le t]+\Bbb E[W_t; t<T].
$$
The first term on the right converges to $1$ as $t\to\infty$. This means that the second converges to $-1$. This is because the Brownian motion most likely spends a lot of its time in the negative half-line before finally getting to $1$.
You can't simply pass  the $t\to\infty$ limit into the inside of the expectation (getting $W_T$ in there), because the family $\{W_{T\wedge t}: t\ge 0\}$ is not uniformly integrable.
The random variable $W_T$ is the "last element" of $\{W_{T\wedge t}: t\ge 0\}$ in the sense that $\lim_{t\to\infty} W^T_t=W_T =1$ a.s. But $W^T_\infty$  doesn't "close" $\{W_{T\wedge t}: t\ge0\}$ as a martingale: $\{W_{T\wedge t}: 0\le t\le\infty\}$ is not a martingale.
